# Sublimetext replace with new line to format arrays from var_dump PHP function

Tags: php, arrays, sublimetext3

I have a huge array from var_dump PHP output and would like to format using sublimetext.

How can i replace [" with \n[" ?

I try using Ctrl+R to enable Regex but still did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Highlight `["`
- Press Alt+F3 to select every instance of `["`
- Press left arrow once to move cursor to the start and then press Enter